# How to rollback to Xcode 6.4, Carthage

Tags: ios, xcode, carthage

I download Xcode 6.4 from here http://adcdownload.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_6.4/Xcode_6.4.dmg . Then select previous Xcode for build:

`~ xcode-select -s "/Applications/Xcode_6.4.app/Contents/Developer"`

But I can't compile libraries with `Carthage`. I get error:

```
2015-09-18 19:13:58.057 xcodebuild[13961:788602] stream error: stream error at offset 8: unsupported version number ('1.04')
```

On other computer after Xcode 7 update, the same issue. Libraries doesn't compile, but errors is different.

```
~ carthage version
0.8.0
```

Cartfile:

```
github "Alamofire/Alamofire" "1.3.1"
```

Comment: i have the exact same issue, did you have any success so far?

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error. I just ran the update command with sudo. Here is the full list of steps that worked for me:

- Renamed Xcode 7.x application to Xcode 7
- Downloaded Xcode 6.4.
- Updated Cartfile to: github "Alamofire/Alamofire" "1.3.1"
- Ran the the carthage update with sudo:

```
 sudo carthage update
```

**Terminal's output:**

```
Januszs-Mac-mini: janusz$ sudo carthage update
Password:
*** Fetching Alamofire
*** Checking out Alamofire at "1.3.1"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/zz/zyxvpxvq6csfxvn_n0000000000000/T/...
*** Building scheme "Alamofire OSX" in Alamofire.xcworkspace
*** Building scheme "Alamofire iOS" in Alamofire.xcworkspace
```

Comment: Exact setup as you -- Xcode 7 running alongside Xcode 6 -- and received the exact same error. Was surprised that running carthage update as an admin fixed the error. Nice catch.

Comment: this should be an error. carthage never should require admin rights

Comment: I don't understand how/why this works with "sudo" but thank you <3

Comment: check your rights, `ls -la /Users/sbuglakov/Library/Caches/org.carthage.CarthageKit/` unfortunately I had no `r` for the user. and even the group has read rights and I were in it, when I tried to look into or rename that cache directory, I was getting the Permission denied error.

Answer (score 2):

Resolved with this command:
mv ~/Library/Developer ~/Library/Developer_moved